# Bootmenu hangs on laptop when exteral USB device is connected

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, usb

I've got my laptop installed with Windows 10 and Elementary OS. First I installed Windows and second Elementary OS so I get a boot menu from Elementary OS. I have got an external mouse connected on a USB drive and when I start the laptop with the mouse connected, the bootmenu does not respond to keyboard input. When I disconnect the mouse and restart the laptop, the problem is solved.

It is not only the mouse, it is with every external USB device.

The laptop is a 2019 HP Spectre X360.

I hope somebody can help me solve this problem.

Andy

Answer (score 1):

From the bios menu, enable legacy support, and this will solve your problem.